# Title page with lines and left adjusted author name at bottom

Tags: titles

I have the following latex test document that sets a title page.

Would like to have a thick horizontal ruling line underneath the title.  I also would like to have the name of the author at the bottom, adjusted to the left, with a thinner ruling line underneath.

```latex
 
     \documentclass[12pt]{book}
              
    \usepackage{geometry}      
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm, top=21mm, bottom=8mm}          
    
    \begin{document}          
    
    \begin{titlepage}     
    
      \begin{center} 
        \title{Fredholm Integral Transforms}     
      \end{center}     
    
      \author{An Author}     
      \date{\today}
     \end{titlepage}          
    
    \maketitle
    
         hello world          
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{ulem}` and `\title{\uline{Fredholm Integral Transforms}}`

Comment: Texworks does not use have the package.  Have found that I can use `\rule{19cm}{5pt}`.

Comment: How can I left adjust the title and author name?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can meet your requirement!!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm, top=21mm, bottom=8mm}

\usepackage{ulem}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
    \begin{document}
\apptocmd{\title}{\raggedright}{}{}%
\apptocmd{\author}{\raggedright\vfill}{}{}%    
    \begin{titlepage} 
    
        \title{\uline{Fredholm Integral Transforms}}

      \author{An Author}    
      \date{\today}
\end{titlepage}
    
    \maketitle
    
hello world
    
    \end{document}
```